# Playwright does not load all of the HTML Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I'm just trying to scrape the titles from the page, but the html that is being loaded with page.inner_html('body') does not include all of the html. I think it may be loaded from JS, but when I look into the network tab in dev tools I cannot seem to find a json or where it's being loaded from. I have tried this with Selenium as well, so there must be something I'm doing fundamentally wrong.

So no items appear from the list, but the regular HTML shows up fine. No amount of waiting for the content to load, will load the information.

```
#import playwright
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

url = 'https://order.mandarake.co.jp/order/listPage/list?categoryCode=07&keyword=naruto&lang=en'

#open url
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    #enable javascript
    
    page.goto(url)
    #enable javascript
    

    #load the page and wait for the page to load
    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")

    #get the html content
    html = page.inner_html("body")

    print(html)

    #close browser
    browser.close()
```

Comment: What data are you trying to get? The data seems there for me, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the webpage isn't loaded content dynamically by `JavaScript` rather it's entirely static HTML DOM

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://order.mandarake.co.jp/order/listPage/list?categoryCode=07&keyword=naruto&lang=en')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')

data = []
for e in soup.select('div.title'):

    d = {
        'title':e.a.get_text(strip=True),
        
        }
    
    data.append(d)

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'title': 'NARUTO THE ANIMATION CHRONICLE\u3000genga made for sale'}, {'title': 'Plex DPCF Haruno Sakura Reboru ring of the eyes'}, {'title': 'Naruto: Shippuden\u3000(replica)  ナルト'}, {'title': 'Naruto: Shippuden\u3000(replica)  ナルト'}, {'title': 'Naruto: Shippuden\u3000(replica)  NARUTO -ナルト-'}, {'title': 'Naruto: Shippuden ナルト\u3000(replica)'}, {'title': 'Naruto Shippuuden\u3000(replica) NARUTO -ナルト-'}, {'title': 'NARUTO -ナルト- 疾風伝\u3000(複製セル)'}, {'title': 'MegaHouse    ちみ メガ Petit Chara Land NARUTO SHIPPUDEN ナルト blast-of-wind intermediary   Even [swirl ナルト special is a volume on ばよ.  
  All 6 types set] inner bag not opened/box damaged'}, {'title': 'NARUTO -ナルト- 疾風伝\u3000(複製セル)'}, {'title': 'NARUTO -ナルト- 疾風伝\u3000(複製セル)'}, {'title': 'NARUTO -ナルト- 疾風伝'}, {'title': 'NARUTO -ナルト- 疾風伝'}, {'title': 'NARUTO -ナルト-'}]
```

Comment: That's interesting that printing the soup won't show it, but when you select the div.title elements it will show it. Any reason for that? And thank you! It worked perfectly.

Comment: @Sweetcheeks12354,Thanks. Actually, I didn't face any issues when I selected element vai devtools . It worked at the same way when turned off JS then I understood it's static html content